# Trouble replicating sklearn logistic regression outputs

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, classification, python

I am trying to create my own logistic regression classifier using scipy.optimize but I am having trouble getting close to the output of sklearn's built in logistic regression function. I am testing it on a binary portion of the iris dataset shown below:

```
from scipy import optimize
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

def costFunc(thetas, X, Y, penalty):
    # Log loss cost function with regularization (except for intercept term)
    sigmoid = 1/(1+np.exp(-(X @ thetas)))
    cost = -1/len(X)*(Y @ np.log(sigmoid+1e-15) \
    +(1-Y) @ np.log(1-sigmoid+1e-15)) \
    +sum(penalty/(2*len(X))*thetas[1:]**2) # 1e-15 added to log to prevent divide by 0 errors  
    return cost

iris = datasets.load_iris() # Load example dataset
thetas = np.zeros(2) # initial coefficients
penalty = 0
x1 = iris.data[:100, 0].reshape(-1, 1)
x2 = iris.data[:100, 1].reshape(-1, 1)
scalerx = StandardScaler().fit(x1) # fit the standard scaler to the training data
scalery = StandardScaler().fit(x2) # fit the standard scaler to the training data
X = np.hstack([scalerx.transform(x1), scalery.transform(x2)])
Y = iris.target[:100]

# Minimize the cost function
coefficients0 = optimize.minimize(costFunc, thetas, args=(X, Y, penalty), method='L-BFGS-B')
```

The coefficient output of this is [127.44071673, -100.51413182] while the following sklearn code

```
logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e15, solver='lbfgs') # regularization set to 0
logreg.fit(X, Y)
coefficients1 = logreg.coef_
```

has an output of [46.14677281, -28.27345264]. I would like to attribute this to differences in the solver, or perhaps the initial coefficients chosen but I'm not certain.

EDIT: I forgot to add in the intercept term into the code, once added in

```
x0 = np.ones((len(x1), 1))
X = np.hstack([x0, scalerx.transform(x1), scalery.transform(x2)])
```

the output becomes [7.59366865,  35.25397633, -21.54576954] for my code vs the
[4.8815577 ,  42.64049218, -26.29487637] for sklearn which is much closer but still somewhat different.

Comment: It will likely be very difficult to answer without reproducible data.  That being said, are you sure you are replicating all the default options if you haven't set them?  __init__(Cs=10, fit_intercept=True, cv=’warn’, dual=False, penalty=’l2’, scoring=None, solver=’lbfgs’, tol=0.0001, max_iter=100, class_weight=None, n_jobs=None, verbose=0, refit=True, intercept_scaling=1.0, multi_class=’warn’, random_state=None)[source]

You may want to focus on the tolerance and maximum iterations.

Comment: Also did you standardize your data in both procedures?

Comment: The data is a dataset built into sklearn. You can reproduce this on your own if you have sklearn installed. Several of the parameters you suggested are not valid for LogisticRegression() but for the ones that did work the value did not change. Data is standardized in all procedures.